# estimating variance when parameters are estimated

Tags: generalized-linear-model, robust-standard-error

I am trying to understand the [sandwich variance estimator](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ecensus/mlesan.pdf). Mainly my confusion is why it is OK to use estimated parameters. I think it boils down to this question. If $f(X_i; \theta),i=1,\ldots,n$ are IID, where the $X_i$ are IID random, $f$ is a known function, and $\theta$ is a parameter, then a consistent estimator of $Var(f(X,\theta)$ is the sample variance,$(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n(f(X_i;\theta)-\overline{f(X_i;\theta)})^2.$ If $\hat\theta$ is a consistent estimator of $\theta$, does it follow that the sample variance of $f(X_i;\hat\theta)$ converges to $Var(f(X,\theta)$?

If expand in a Taylor series
$(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^nf(X_i;\hat\theta)^2=(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^nf(X_i;\theta)^2+(\hat\theta-\theta)(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n2f(X_i;\theta)\frac{d}{d\theta}f(X_i;\theta)$ plus lower order terms, it looks like it should work since $\hat\theta-\theta$ converges to $0$. If the other terms are well behaved. Is the right argument, at least in the simple case where the Taylor series is OK to take?